# Exploding (and imploding) Dice in Excel

Tags: excel, dice

I am trying to write a formula which will simulate the roll of an N sided dice, however this needs to explode when an N is rolled, and when a 1 is rolled it needs to re-roll, and subtract the next roll. If the next roll is a N, it explodes and subtracts even more.
Rolling a 1 after an explosion has no further effects.

How can I get this as either a formula or VBA formula in Excel? [A code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183073/simulating-exploding-dice/185170) from several months ago tackled the first part of the explosion, with the result as

```
=A1*INT(-LOG(RAND(),A1))-INT(RAND()*(1-A1))
```

A few example rolls, using N=10,

2-9 all as normal

1 -> 5 ===> -4

10 -> 5 ===> 15

10 -> 10 -> 10 -> 4 ====> 34

1 -> 10 -> 4 ====> -13

1 -> 10 -> 1 ====> -10

I have tried a few attempts but everything has resulted in NA so is not helpful here. Thanks!

Comment: What other formulas have you tried and are you trying to get something different than the code-golfed formula (which seems to generate a correct distribution). If you've tried some VBA code, please show us what you have so far.

Comment: As explained in the question, rolling a 1 needs to also have an affect, not just the max number. I will find my code and post it here in a bit